# how to get iPhone device Crash Log file without syncing to Itune

Tags: ios5

I need to access iphone crash log file via programmatically. I trying to write a crash report feature that when you launch the app after a crash, it will offer to send the crash report to the server. I can't find how to get the crash log within the app. I saw there is a framework that doing so (PLCrashReporter), however this framework is large and I don't need most of it's features. is any library or IOS code to read crash log file .

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://quincykit.net/ for your self hosted php based solution, contains all you need. Or a hosted service, there are plenty out there right now.